# remove particular value from an inbox box value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove value from an input box with match value.

```
   onclick(value){
    var array = document.getElementById('related-products-field').value;
     alert(array);
    //array = 339,340,339,340,338 
    // if(value==339) ,339 should be remove

     }
```

Comment: can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: It depends you can use regular expression, if you are looking for some numbers or if you are looking for a specific thing?

Comment: array=339,340,338  input =339 , output =340,338

Comment: Define your input by it’s id then use indexOf to check if in array then if true set the value as empty string somthing like this code.      var input_field= document.getElementById("#input_field");
    if(array.indexOf(value)>-1){
    input_fueld.value='';
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions or if you are looking for special characters such as:

```
string.indexOf(yourInput) !== -1;
```

or

```
var entryArray = array.split(',');
var output =entryArray.filter(el=>el!==parseInt(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` like below.

```js
var array=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
function f(){
    y=array.filter(x=>x!==parseInt(document.getElementById("hi").value));
    console.log(y);
}
```

```html
<input id="hi" type="number">
<button onclick="f()">click</button>
```

Comment: *I want to remove value from an input box with match value.* This removes a value from an array, not the value from the field.

Comment: _array=339,340,338 input =339 , output =340,338 _ as mention by OP in his comment @ScottMarcus (i think title will be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

See the comments inline below:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("test");
var vals = [339,340,338];

txt.addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Cache a reference to the input that triggered the event
  var self = this;
  // Loop over the array
  vals.forEach(function(item){
    // Convert the field value to a number and compare against the array item
    if(+self.value === item){
      // Remove the value from the field
      self.value = self.value.replace(item, "");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<p>Type in a value and then hit TAB<p>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using array splice

```js
 var remove = function(value){
   var array = document.getElementById('related-products-field').value;
   arr = [339,340,338]
   console.log(arr.indexOf(parseInt(array)))
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(parseInt(array)),1)
   alert(arr);
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="related-products-field" >

<button onclick="remove()">remove</button>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqjZYM?editors=1011